# How does MLC FLASH store multiple bits per cell?

Tags: flash-memories

How does MLC FLASH store multiple bits per cell? I understand that each cell is one MOSFET, are the different bits represented by multiple voltage levels (as opposed to just high/low, which would then be SLC)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so an MLC flash chip that stores 4 bits per cell would have 16 different charge states. In general \$2^n\$ charge states for \$n\$ bits. A modern 8TB QLC drive might have 8 dies of [1Tb each](https://www.techinsights.com/products/mfr-1812-801).